# How to assign a variable in unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a variable called `TIMESTAMP = 04/12/2017 03:45:00`, and wrote a script to convert that to this: `/2017_04_12/03_45/`.  The script is:

```
echo $TIMESTAMP |
     tr ' :' // |
     awk -F/ '{ printf("/%s_%s_%s/%s_%s/\n",$3,$1,$2,$4,$5); }'
```

This works great!

Now, how do I assign the output of this thing to a new variable, `MYVAR`?  I tried this:

```
MYVAR=$(echo $TIMESTAMP |
        tr ' :' // |
        awk -F/ '{ printf("/%s_%s_%s/%s_%s/\n",$3,$1,$2,$4,$5); }')
```

with no luck.

Then I tried this also:

```
MYVAR=`echo $TIMESTAMP |
       tr ' :' // |
       awk -F/ '{ printf("/%s_%s_%s/%s_%s/\n",$3,$1,$2,$4,$5); }'`
```

again, with no luck.

In either case, I keep getting the error message:

```
04/12/2017: no found
```

Comment: Its not clear from your post, but are you putting spaces around the `=`?  Not allowed!

Comment: `MYVAR=$(echo $TIMESTAMP | tr ' :' // | awk -F/ '{ printf("/%s_%s_%s/%s_%s/\n",$3,$1,$2,$4,$5); }')` work great for me

Comment: Try `TIMESTAMP="04/12/2017 03:45:00"`

Comment: sorry, i left out the ` sign ... so the second attempt should actually have a ` at the beginning as well ...

Comment: @hugo Sorry, I edited at the same time as you did.

Comment: Both your commands work here as they are.

Comment: Are you missing the `echo`? Then you'd get something like your error message.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $MYVAR`? Because the commands seem ok to me, both worked (I'm using bash 4.1.2, not sure if it's related to bash version - probably not, but you never know)

Comment: ok, i think i see what my issue is ... the variable TIMESTAMP is being produced from another routine that is converting something like 1491983100 using this line: TIMESTAMP=$(uxtime 1491983100).  that's why the resulting TIMESTAMP value doesn't contain " ", only 04/12/2017 03:45:00.

Comment: still no luck, no matter what i try!  :-(

Comment: @lookiluke, the **value** shouldn't contain quotes. The correct kind of quotes are syntactic ones (ones that are instructions to the shell), not literal ones (ones that are part of your data). A quote mark that's in your data isn't going to be honored as syntax.

Comment: @lookiluke, that said -- the code you have in this question can't and won't create the bug you're reporting right now on its own. Please consider deleting your question, editing it to contain a [mcve], and then undeleting it (the temporary deletion being so you can't get downvotes/close votes while you're in the process of editing).

Comment: @lookiluke, ...so, `TIMESTAMP="04/12/2017 03:45:00"` isn't actually putting quotes into the `TIMESTAMP` variable's value; it's just informing the shell that everything *inside* of those quotes should be treated as a single value. If you've run `foo="hello world"`, then the value of `foo` is just `hello world` -- but referencing it as `"$foo"` instead of `$foo` is telling the shell that it should be kept together as one string instead of split into two. (That's actually implicitly the case in some contexts, such as assignments, but when you're not sure, using quotes is the safe approach).

Comment: BTW, as an aside, all-caps variable names are specified for variables with meaning to the OS or shell itself, whereas lowercase variable names are reserved for application use.  See the relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: @Charles Duffy, ok understood, thanks. i will delete my original question and resubmit the entire code that's giving me the error in a minimal, complete, and verifiable format!  :-)

Comment: Since you don't have any answers here, you can resubmit in the same question after editing it -- it's only after someone has answered it that major changes to a question (particularly, changes that could invalidate an answer) are frowned on.

Comment: (BTW, `TIMESTAMP = 04/12/2017 03:45:00` isn't actually a valid assignment -- it would need to be something like `TIMESTAMP='04/12/2017 03:45:00'` to be correct).

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your timestamp is not good?

try this

```
$ myvar=$(date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" | awk -F'[ /:]' -v OFS=_ '
                                      {print "/" $1,$2,$3 "/" $4,$5 "/"}')

$ echo "$myvar"
/2017_04_20/12_31/
```